# Trimming whatever that comes after a certain symbol and extract a certain number of sections from string

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column containing numbers like this '12.34.56.78', '23.45.67.89' etc. and the numbers always come in four sections. However,I am only intersted in the first three sections. If the number of digits in each section is always stable, the solution would be to use SUBSTRING, however, numbers such as '123.456.78.9' is expected as well. Therefore, the only common rule that can be used is the dots.
Is there any way to cut off whatever that comes after the third dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the [split_part](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) function. In this function you specify 1. the string of interest, 2. your delimiter, in your case the ".", and 3. which part of the fragmented string you are interested in returning. In your case you will always have four string fragments.

Here is split_part in practice:

```
SELECT
      '12.34.56.78' AS original_string
    , SPLIT_PART(original_string,'.',1) AS string_fragment_1
    , SPLIT_PART(original_string,'.',2) AS string_fragment_2
    , SPLIT_PART(original_string,'.',3) AS string_fragment_3
    , SPLIT_PART(original_string,'.',1)::varchar || '.' || SPLIT_PART(original_string,'.',2) || '.' || SPLIT_PART(original_string,'.',3) AS final_output.
```

I believe the last column returns your desired output. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this like so:

```sql
select original_num,
       substring(original_num, 1, (length(original_num) - position('.' in reverse(original_num)))) as new_num
  from a_table;
```

with an example on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bKWABU335wSU6ASpqagzG7/0).

Answer (score -1):

We can try using a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT num, REGEXP_REPLACE(num, '\.\d+$', '') AS num_out
FROM yourTable;
```